# TypeError: Cannot read property 'coins' of null Discord.js error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const db = require('quick.db');
module.exports = {
    name: 'bal',
    description: "Check your coin balance.",
    execute(message, args) {
        let profile = db.get(`${message.author.id}`)
        if (!profile.coins) return message.lineReply('You currently have 0 coins.')
        message.lineReply(`You currently have ${profile.coins} coins.`);
    }
}
```

This is the command file for the balance command for my discord.js bot.
That script outputs this in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'coins' of null
```

Here's more info about the database: https://quickdb.js.org/

Comment: It looks like db.get() might be a Promise and may need to be awaited or chained with a .then

Comment: @Hyetigran - No, if that were the case `profile.coins` would be `undefined`, not an error. The error says that `profile` is `null`.

Comment: The error tells you that `profile` is `null`. So you have to find out why ```db.get(`${message.author_id}`)``` is returning `null`. (I'm surprised by that, because like Hyetigran, I would have expected it to return a promise, but perhaps it's an old-fashioned callback-based API.) (Side note: ```db.get(`${message.author_id}`)``` is a convoluted way to write `db.get(message.author_id)`. :-) )

Comment: Please add details about which database you are using, only then can we diagnose fully what your issue is.

Comment: Could we also see your database setup code. We can go no further without it.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'some object' of null`

You are accessing a property of an object that is null. For example, document.getElementById('stuff') returns null. So adding `.examplevalue` will cause the error.

Test if an object is valid before accessing its property. (The object in question is `profile`).

Your `db.get()` is returning null, as in no value. Make sure that A) your database is set up correctly, and B) that the syntax for accessing said database is also correct. Otherwise this error is bound to be thrown.